# Saving NSManagedObjectContext without error handling?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I usually write `managedObjectContext().save(nil)`.

I think most of the cases you do not need a bulletproof, 100% code coverage, even apple engineers said in 2014 CloudKit lecture that error handling in Core Data is a good if have but not crucial feature, compare i.e. to `CloudKit`, where it is really important to deal with returned errors.

I would be curious at what cases is it worth to deal with error in `Core-Data` and how do you deal with it? Only plot error out to terminal? Send error reports to backend?

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: I have written Swift, but Objective-C can be also, it is relating `Core-Data` framework

Comment: Why do you say "of course"?

Comment: @Droppy in Swift function is called with `()` and in Objective-C with `[]` notation

Answer (score 4):

Saving the context can fail. If you pass `nil` for the `error` parameter, you will lose information on what has gone wrong.

Failure while saving context can have severe consequences, for example, a user can loss his or her data. You may want to log information about such an event if it happens in production (and in a sufficiently complex application it is not unlikely to happen). Without knowing what the error was, it would be virtually impossible to debug.